# Twitter boot strap side nav

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Can someone please assist me in figuring out how to turn this code snippet of a bootstrap side-bar to a normal top nav when the media queries kick in for mobile devices, the nav needs to be static at the top as well. The side-bar is inside a container that moves margin-left: -280px; when the side-bar is toggled/open. Thank you in advance to any one who can assist me with this.
Here is the HTML

```
<div class="page-container sidebar-collapsed">
<div class="sidebar-menu">
    <header class="logo"> <a href="#" class="sidebar-icon"> <span class="fa fa-bars"></span> </a> <a href="#"> <span id="logo" class="fa fa-html5 fa-5x"></span><!--<img id="logo" src="" alt="Logo"/>--> </a> </header>
        <div style="border-top:1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7)"></div>
          <div class="menu">
            <ul id="menu" >
              <li id="menu-home" class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i><span>Home</span></a></li>
              <li id="menu-comunicacao" ><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i><span>Services</span></a>
                <ul id="menu-comunicacao-sub" >
                  <li id="menu-mensagens" style="width: 220px" ><a href="#">Web design</a>
                  </li>
                  <li id="menu-arquivos" ><a href="#">Graphic Design</a></li>
                  <li id="menu-arquivos" ><a href="#">Event Management</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li id="menu-academico" ><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span>Contact us</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the css

```
.page-container {
  min-width: 1260px;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
.page-container.sidebar-collapsed {
  transition: all 100ms linear;
  transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back {
  margin-left: -280px;
  transition: all 300ms linear;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-menu {
  width: 65px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-menu {
  width: 280px;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .sidebar-icon {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .sidebar-icon {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed .logo {
  padding: 21px;
  height: 136px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back .logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  height: 136px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #logo {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #logo {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed #menu span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 50ms linear;
}

.page-container.sidebar-collapsed-back #menu span {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  transition-delay: 300ms;
}

.sidebar-menu {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  width: 280px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #303641;
  color: #aaabae;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  /*box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);*/
  z-index: 1;
}

#menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#menu li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li ul {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
}

#menu li a {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #aaabae;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 2;
}
#menu li a span{
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
#menu li a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #333944;
  border-left: 3px solid #D19B3D;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color 250ms ease-in-out, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
}

#menu li.active > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  border-left: 3px solid #D19B3D;
  background-color: #4F5B69;  
}

#menu ul li { background-color: #2b303a; }

#menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#menu li ul {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: 100%;
  top: -1px;
  background-color: #2b303a;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(69, 74, 84, 0.7);
}

#menu li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu li li ul {
  right: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  top: -1px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.1s linear;
}

#menu li li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#menu .fa { 
  margin-right: 5px; 
  font-size: 18px; 
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 21px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sidebar-icon {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #454a54;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #888;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.fa-html5 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

here is the javascript

```
var toggle = true;

$(".sidebar-icon").click(function() {                
  if (toggle){
    $(".page-container").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#menu span").css({"position":"relative"});
    }, 1000);
  }
  else {
    $(".page-container").addClass("sidebar-collapsed").removeClass("sidebar-collapsed-back");
    $("#menu span").css({"position":"absolute"});
  }

toggle = !toggle;

});
```